# How to make Windows generate all thumbnails in a folder without navigating through it?

Tags: windows-10, video, windows-explorer, icons, thumbnails

I got a folder with thousands (20,000+) of MP4 video files, the thumbnails show correctly on Windows 10 but Explorer only generates the thumbnail when the file icon shows up on the screen. Worse is, the thumbnail generation process stops if the icon leaves the screen so I can't just PG+DOWN through the whole folder and leave it working in the background; I have to wait for the visible icons to finish generating their thumbnail, press PG+DWN (or scroll) so new icons show up and the process resumes. This is extremely time consuming taking into account the amount of files needed to be generated and that I can max show 20.30 icons at the time, each time needing to scroll down to continue the process.

Is there a way to make Windows generate all the thumbnails in a folder without this process? Mind you, I don't want the thumbnails to be in a separate image file, I want the native Windows thumbnail to show up instead of the icon.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is reaching back a bit, but it's been an ongoing problem and there is now an solution, so I will put it here for Google traffic; Dmitry Bruhov has created a slick little OS addition to the explorer context menu that preloads all thumbs in a given folder. His git is here:

https://github.com/bruhov/WinThumbsPreloader/

It still takes a little bit for them to load, but now you don't need to sit there and page through the whole folder -- quite lifechanging for certain things. (Such as directories full of images, something most people have!)